# Create A Service And Allow Only One Bundle To Hold That Service At any Time

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to create a service such that once it is created it only allows itself to be held by a single consumer/bundle at any one time. (If this is against the philosophy/specification of OSGi then that obviously provides a quick answer but reference to the OSGi specs. stating this would be appreciated.)

To implement such a requirement I implemented the [ServiceFactory](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceFactory.html) interface thinking that whenever there was a requirement for the service the [`getService(Bundle bundle, ServiceRegistration<S> registration)`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceFactory.html#getService(org.osgi.framework.Bundle,%20org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration)) method would be called and it would be where I could determine if the `Bundle` was a new consumer or not and act accordingly.

It appears that this is not the case in the scenario I have tested this in.

Using a Apache Karaf and instantiating a consumer of the Service via Blueprint it would seem that the `getService` method is never called. Instead the consumer's binding method for the service is called directly but injecting a proxy service object.

While I understand that Blueprint uses proxies surely there is still the obligation of the `ServiceFactory` contract to fulfil even if it's a proxy object consuming the service?

Why do I want to do this?
I am attempting to wrap JavaFX and the `Stage` class and because JavaFX isn't OSGi friendly I am attempting to co-ordinate access to the `Stage` object. I'm aware that there are frameworks such as Drombler but a brief look at them made me think that it doesn't suit my use case. They appear too restrictive for my needs e.g. I don't necessarily wish to layout an application in the manner Drombler uses.

Comment: I would not design a service in the way that I expect that it will be used only once. If you implement such solutions, you will end up in a chaotic framework where only the one knows what to touch who implemented the code originally. I would also advise not to use Blueprint. Aries Blueprint is super-buggy, even the basic use-cases are unstable. Even if the technology itself was stable, the concept behind is also "buggy" that makes the system unstable.

Comment: Hi Balazs. To clarify, the service wouldn't be used just one time but only held by a single consumer at any time. Once such a consumer relinquished command of the service, that same service would become available to another bundle. You make some interesting comments about Aries Blueprint and although I could choose to NOT use blueprint, my use case considers that a third-party consumer of my service might use Blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by a consumer. ServiceFactory does give you the chance to create a separate instance of a service per **bundle** that calls `getService` on your service. It's not clear from your question but I suspect you weren't seeing the `getService` invoked multiple times because you were fetching the service from the same consumer bundle. In this case, ServiceFactory simply returns the same object repeatedly.

As for your general question about restricting access to a single consumer, no that really goes against the OSGi philosophy. I'm sorry I don't have a spec reference for you but the clue is in the name: it's a **service** that is available to all.

Comment: Hi Neil. To clarify, `getService()` is NEVER called when a consumer of that service is deployed. I created two separate bundles which both require the service, one of them being a 'dummy' bundle to test out this scenario. In both instances, when they are deployed (via Blueprint) the `getService` method is never called but instead in the bind methods I see a proxy object passed in.

Comment: I accept that the OSGi definition of a service implies that it is available to all without regard to the number of consumers but I do think there is a case to be made to allow a limit on the number of consumers. In this case I am attempting to control access to the JavaFX `Stage` object rather than allow several bundles intentionally, maliciously or accidentally deployed, to randomly grab the Stage object. I'm sure there are other scenarios not related to JavaFX where such a restriction is required: it's available to all but only a definite number of consumers may interact with it at any time.

Comment: Well you're using Blueprint so all bets are off. Possibly you have to actually invoke a method on the service, which will force the proxy to resolve its real backing service. This kind of unpredictability is just another reason to hate Blueprint. As to your second comment -- I know nothing about JavaFX but it sounds like maybe the Stage shouldn't be directly published as a service, but rather something that wraps it and offers a higher-level, restricted API.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware that there are frameworks such as Drombler but a brief look at them made me think that it doesn't suit my use case. They appear too restrictive for my needs e.g. I don't necessarily wish to layout an application in the manner Drombler uses.

Please note that the layout of *Drombler FX* applications is pluggable so you can provide your own implementation tailored to your needs. This allows you to get the most out of *Drombler FX* and *JavaFX*.

While this feature is available for some time, there is now a [new tutorial trail](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.11/docs/tutorial/application-layout.html#applicationLayout) explaining it in more detail.